# Mootools Fx.Scroll() giving wrong/delayed div.getScroll()

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am doing a `FX.Scroll()` with Mootools 1.3.2 and making `console.log()` directly after the Fx.Scroll command.

**Q:** why does `div.getScroll()` does not get me the "after-Fx.Scroll()" value? but instead the value before the `Fx.Scroll()`?

([jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/2WuSw/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is event-based programming. Fx.Scroll is an instance of Fx, when any animation / tweening is complete, it will fire an `oncomplete` event. you are currently outputting at the time of click, not after the tweening is done. since it's not a CSS3 transition, the property does not get set str away and then interpolated by the css ui thread - it is actually moving it on a point by point basis in a setTimeout (so detached from current execution scope/thread).

http://jsfiddle.net/2WuSw/1/

```
scrollEff = new Fx.Scroll(spinAreaDiv, {
    wait: false,
    duration: 1000,
    offset: {
        'x': 0,
            'y': 0
    },
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut,
    onComplete: function(){
        console.log(this.element.getScroll().x);
    }
});
```

as you can see above, I am passing an onComplete event handler.

you can also late-bind later.

```
// or use `complete:once`
scrollEff.addEvent('complete', function(){
    console.log(this.element.getScroll().x);
});
```

Comment: Great, now I know a bit more. That was what I was missing. Thank you (again!). I like Mootools, I think it deserves more attention than it gets so I invest some time on it :)